# Is there a word for people who are afraid of change?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

We would like to know if there is a single word to describe fear of change.

> Bob did not like change, he was a _____.

Comment: Try looking up *neophobe*.

Comment: [Conservative](http://thesaurus.com/browse/conservative?s=ts).

Comment: Already-mentioned *[neophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neophobia)* looks suitable, but also see  [Continuing to do something just because it was done before, without knowing why](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8901) and [Words describing the pat acceptance of a thought or practice simply because "that's how it's done."](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54007) and  [Word for a person with a negative attitude](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15824), and [Single word for people who are like "a frog in the well"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/51451),

Comment: @TimLymington Though sounds right, I find few instances of *neophobe* in Google Books results. The term is more common in the forms *neophobia* and *neophobic*, even which are rare. Agreed, it seems the word that comes closest.

Comment: Hello Emilio and welcome. To answer the question reliably, we will need more details, context, an example sentence, something, anything. As it stands, the title and body don't even match — one asks for a word for people, the other for a feeling. And what do you mean by "describe"? What do you mean by "fear"? Are you looking for a technical term or a vivid idiom? A noun, an adjective, a verb? Please put the same amount of effort into your questions you expect people to put into their answers. You can improve the question by clicking the "edit" link. Then it can be reopened.

Comment: The example given in itself does not have any element of fear — only dislike. In the current situation of inventing “phobia” words to describe antagonism, often to behaviour rather than people, I think questions like this should be edited or closed.

Comment: What about "human"?

Answer (score 11):

I see *neophobe* has been suggested at least a couple of times, but I personally find this term a little clinical. There are many ways to describe someone resistant to change, depending on the cause for resistance.

In the negative sense, a *fuddy-duddy*, *fogy*, or *mossback* is someone, perhaps an older someone, with a dislike for recent developments in fashion, technology, or culture (and by implication is somewhat unfashionable, *luddite*, or *philistine*); they are *set in their ways*.

More positive, or at least neutral, words for those with a preference for the old ways include *traditionalist* or *classicist*; they might gently be dismissed as members of the  *old guard* or *old school* who repeat the *old line*. Resistance to change that derives from moderation and caution makes someone *conservative*, *reticent*, or *leery*.

But if one clings to one idea and expresses intolerance for others, he becomes a *die-hard* or *hidebound*, and any synonyms for chauvinism, fearfulness, or intolerance may suffice. Those who not only resist change, but seek to reverse previous change, are *reactionaries*.

A *square* or *stick-in-the-mud* is resistant to anything unconventional; they have an *establishment* or *bourgeois* mentality. Fear of change due to small-mindedness is characteristic of *insular*, *provincial*, *parochial*, *small-town*, or *pedestrian* thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why this question has come up again after eight years, but:

> A person who *dislikes* change is **conservative** and perhaps also “a Conservative”

I am not aware of any established word in the English language meaning “fear of change”, and people may fear change for a variety of reasons, justified as well as unjustified. Of course someone may invent a *phobia* word for this, but I fear it will not change my somewhat conservative attitude to this.

Answer (score 0):

Luddite could work depending on the context.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why you think this is a good option and provide links. See [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: This has already been suggested in another answer on this page.