# What is the word for fear of growth?

Tags: language-change

Is there a word or term for people who have a fear of growth?

Comment: What kind of growth? Like getting taller? Are they terrified by plants? Are they afraid of personal development?

Comment: Very close related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107922  Are you two married?  Is this some sort of bet or spat?

Comment: Growth related to success - personal or professional development.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, we are married but no bet or spat. We're trying to find the best way to describe this fear of growth/change for the better.

Comment: ......anorexic?

Comment: If you are trying to improve technique and have a paragraph ready for critique, consider asking on [Writers SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com).  Your signons should work there as here.  Writers SE won't suggest replacement words so much as different ways of wording things to make them clear, or concise, or striking, etc, if you can describe what it is you are aiming for.

Comment: *Jonah Complex* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_Complex This seems to hit the nail right on the head for a fear of "growth related to success - personal or professional development."

Comment: See also, (if you can) Goud, N. (1994). Jonah Complex: The fear of growth. Journal of Humanistic Education & Development, 32(3), 98-111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At http://www.fun-with-words.com/phobias_o-q.html is a delightful list of 'phobia words'. Perhaps appropriate here is:

**obesophobia** Fear of gaining weight. [ID, CE]

but probably more relevant is:

**prosophobia** Fear of progress. [ID, CE, WP]

The references are perhaps not the most authoritative:

ID: The Insomniac's Dictionary of the Outrageous, Odd, and Unusual by Paul Hellweg.

CE: Crazy English: The Ultimate Joy Ride Through Our Language by Richard Lederer.

WP: Words at Play: Quips, Quirks, and Oddities by O. V. Michaelsen. Also in The Wordplay Almanac by O. V. Michaelsen.

Comment: Thank you Edwin!  Prosophobia is a great word to describe this fear!!